# Linux: Calling a function within a case

Tags: bash, function, switch-statement

I am trying to set up a menu system where on selection it runs a function. In my case is runs the 'testfunc' function. However is it fails giving the error; testfunc: command not found.

My case statement looks like this;

```
case "$mainMenuInput" in
   1)testfunc ;;
esac

function testfunc{
    echo "This is a test"
}
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You have to define testfunc first. Bash reads line by line without any compilation, so as written, testfunc is not defined at the point testfunc is called.

Comment: I agree with @zanerock.  Simply move your function definition before the case statement.  Also, add a space between `testfunc` and `{`.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Shell scripts are executed statement at a time. The function is only known from the point you define it. You have to move it before the call.

Comment: thanks that worked perfectly. I didn't realise function had to be defined before calling them. Thanks again.